# Calculating the Net Present Value (NPV)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, finance, geometric-series

When input the apropriate data is subbed into the equation we get:

$$NPV=\sum_{t=0}^\infty\frac{200}{1.1^t}$$

I have been told that the second term looks like
$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty\frac{200}{1.1^t} =\frac{200}{0.1}=2000$$

Could someone explain how the second term can end up being written as $\frac{200}{0.1}$?

Comment: What is the particular difficulty you're facing? You just plug in different values of $t$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

$\frac {200} {1.1^i}$ is the general term of a geometric sequence.

Answer (score 2):

When you sum a geometric series, you have
$$
S_N = \sum_{k=0}^N a^k = 1 + a + a^2 + \ldots + a^N\\
aS_n = a\sum_{k=0}^N a^k = a + a^2 + a^3 + \ldots + a^{N+1}
$$
now subtract both sides to get
$$
S_N - aS_N = 1 - a^{N+1},
$$
which implies
$$
S_N = \frac{1-a^{N+1}}{1-a}.
$$

As $N \to \infty$, if $0 < a < 1$, we have $a^{N+1} \to 0$, so
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} S_N = \frac{1}{1-a}.
$$

Can you simplify your series to fit this result?